# How to catch and prevent alt code character from printing?

Tags: autohotkey

How to catch and prevent an Alt Code character from printing?

- OS: Windows 10 Enterprise
- AHK Ver: 1.1.30.03

My AutoHotkey script implements additional paste functionality using the Right <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys combined with a qualifying Numpad key. For this to work, I need to press the keys in the following order: Right <kbd>Alt</kbd> + [Desired Numpad key] + <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

The script :

```
RAlt & Shift::
; Place the cursor at the start of the pasted text
If GetKeyState("Numpad5", "P") {
    Clip := Clipboard
    SendInput %Clip%
    Sleep 10
    Loop, Parse, Clip
        SendInput {Left}
}
...other Numpad # functionalities here using Else If's...
Return
```

The problem is that after performing a shortcut, the corresponding Alt Code character will print followed by the clipboard contents. I've been able to resolve the issue by adding a backspace command :

```
RAlt & Shift::
; Place the cursor at the start of the pasted text
If GetKeyState("Numpad5", "P") {
    Clip := Clipboard
    SendInput %Clip%
    Sleep 10
    Loop, Parse, Clip
        SendInput {Left}
    SendInput {Backspace}
}
...other Numpad # functionalities here using Else If's...
Return
```

But I want to "catch" this Alt Code character and prevent it from printing instead of deleting it afterwards. The solution shouldn't prevent me from using Alt Codes while the script is running. Is there a "buffer" containing the Alt Code character that I could clear out before printing the clipboard contents?